# Application of preset properties QGIS layer to another imported shp

Tags: qgis, layers, style

In QGIS I import the same shp files during days (continuously fieldwork).
For processing in QGIS I set the properties of layer (imported shp)- Style, Labels, Actions, Display.
In these days I have to set the properties of every imported shp separately and manually.

Is it possible apply this all settings (properties of layer) to another imported shp? ...Is it possible to export complete settings of displaying layer and import the same to another layer?

Answer (score 5):

You simply have to save your style file(.qml/.sld).

[image]
and everytime you import a new shape file, just load that style file.

Comment: Thanks, ok! But my problem is solved only partly- Labels are not set (I still have to set manually, which labels I want to view. Style, Actions, Display are ok thanks to setting from .qml file.

Comment: Solved (google) :)  

It's a bug. Use the following workaround:

    Open the layer properties dialog

    Load the style

    Cancel the dialog

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13667